# mysql Apagar todos os registros de uma tabela exceto o primeiro

Tags: mysql, delete

Pessoal alguém sabe dizer onde estou errando? ou se é possível fazer isso?

Escrevi a query assim:

```
DELETE FROM reservas WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID,IDORIGEM FROM reservas WHERE ID='387' and IDORIGEM='387');
```

O campo idorigem mantém sempre o mesmo valor do primeiro registro que é o que não quero que seja excluido.

exemplo:

```
ID IDORIGEM
387 387
490 387
510 387
650 387
```

o mysql está dando essa mensagem de erro:

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Só pra constar, este erro aparece quando você tenta modificar uma tabela e ao mesmo tempo usá-la em uma *subquery*. Isto serve para proteger a consistência do DB.

No seu caso, nem há razão para a *subquery* existir, pois basta fazer isso:

```
DELETE FROM reservas WHERE id != 387
```

Não há sentido em buscar um ID que você já sabe qual é.

---

**Atualizando a resposta**, já que a pergunta mudou (mas a lógica é a mesma).

Se quiser preservar todos os 387, independente de qual dos 2 campos está:

```
DELETE FROM reservas WHERE id != 387 AND idorigem != 387
```

Ou seja, apague de `reservas` os registros cujo `id` não seja 387 e cujo `idorigem` não seja 387.

Quanto ao erro, é por você estar usando `SELECT id, idorigem` numa expressão que só espera uma coluna. Se der só um `SELECT id`, resolve o erro 1241, e volta pro 1093, que sabiamente foi criado para evitar uso conflitante de *subquery*.

Comment: então bacco acho que fiz a consulta de forma errada:

Comment: Acontece. Com o tempo você pega a prática. O importante no caso é saber que `!=` significa "diferente de". Ou seja, "delete da reservas os registros em que o id for diferente de 387".

Comment: olá Bacco. Acabei escrevendo a consulta errada. Eu editei a pergunta novamente. Você pode ver onde estou errando por favor?

Comment: O que eu tinha respondi do continua sendo a solução pro seu problema. Subquery não vai te ajudar em nada, e não é assim que se usa. Atualizei a resposta, de qq forma.

Comment: Se tiver alguma duvida, só avisar que eu procuro explicar melhor. Pode comentar aqui que eu complemento. Pra mim é mais importante vc entender a lógica do que só funcionar.

Comment: blz. Bacco. Realmente vc tem razão. Eu entendi sim. Obrigado pela ajuda.